# upgrading my react-native-web project. webpack dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-native-web

I have recently updated my react-native-web project to use a more recent react native version to use a more recent expo version.

with the help of npm I have now a fully functional updated code running on ios and android.

However I have still difficulties running it on webpack with different problems related (to the best of my understanding) to a webpack that needs to be updated as well to a higher version (2 -> 3or4).

in this process I have found difficulties matching the right webpack version to the right dev-server and cli.

here is my package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-expo-web": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "0.9.9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "1.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "docz": "^0.12.16",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.7",
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "jest-expo": "^30.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^2.0.1",
    "react-styleguidist": "^8.0.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry-web.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean && npm cache clean --force",
    "make": "yarn",
    "docu:dev": "docz dev",
    "docu:build": "docz build",
    "web": "webpack-dev-server -d --config ./webpack.config.js  --env dev --inline --hot --colors --content-base app/ --history-api-fallback",
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --env dev --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --env prod --config ./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^4.4.1",
    "@sentry/cli": "^1.31.0",
    "audit": "0.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
    "expo": "^30.0.0",
    "expo-analytics": "1.0.7",
    "expo-firebase-crashlytics": "1.0.0",
    "expo-web": "0.0.14",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "jsc-android": "^224109.1.0",
    "mobx": "4",
    "mobx-react": "5.1.0",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "16.5.1",
    "react-art": "16.5.1",
    "react-css-blur": "^1.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-markdown": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-simple-markdown": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.9.0",
    "react-native-web-svg": "1.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "~2.3.1",
    "sentry-expo": "^1.11.0",
    "sweetalert": "2.1.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "ws": "^6.0.0"
  }
```

And now I would like to know and understand what I should change web-wise to make my yarn run web script work again, basically.

```js
//web/webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, "./");

// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// 'node_module'.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
 test: /\.js$/,
 // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.

 include: [
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "src"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-navigation"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-tab-view"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-paper"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-vector-icons"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/@expo/samples"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/@expo/vector-icons"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-platform-touchable"),
 ],
 use: {
  loader: "babel-loader",
  options: {
   // cacheDirectory: false,
   babelrc: false,
   sourceMaps: true,
   // minimize: false,
   // Babel configuration (or use .babelrc)
   // This aliases 'react-native' to 'react-native-web' and includes only
   // the modules needed by the app.
   plugins: [
    "expo-web",
    "react-native-web",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    ["transform-runtime", { helpers: true, polyfill: true, regenerator: true }],
   ],
   // The 'react-native' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
   presets: ["react-native"],
  },
 },
};

// This is needed for loading css
const cssLoaderConfiguration = {
 test: /\.css$/,
 use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
};

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
 test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
 use: {
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
   name: "[name].[ext]",
  },
 },
};

const ttfLoaderConfiguration = {
 test: /\.ttf$/,
 use: [
  {
   loader: "file-loader",
   options: {
    name: "./fonts/[hash].[ext]",
   },
  },
 ],
 include: [
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "./src/assets/fonts"),
  path.resolve(appDirectory, "node_modules/react-native-vector-icons"),
 ],
};

module.exports = {
 // your web-specific entry file
 entry: path.resolve(appDirectory, "src/index.js"),
 devtool: "#eval-source-map",
 // mode: 'development',

 // configures where the build ends up
 output: {
  filename: "bundle.js",
  publicPath: "/assets/",
  path: path.resolve(appDirectory, "./app/assets"),
 },

 module: {
  rules: [
   babelLoaderConfiguration,
   cssLoaderConfiguration,
   imageLoaderConfiguration,
   ttfLoaderConfiguration,
  ],
 },

 plugins: [
  // process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' must be true for production
  // builds to eliminate development checks and reduce build size. You may
  // wish to include additional optimizations.
  // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/206#issuecomment-358015555
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"), //JSON.stringify("production")
   __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" || true,
  }),
 ],

 resolve: {
  // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
  // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
  // '.web.js'.
  symlinks: false,
  extensions: [".web.js", ".js", ".json"],
  alias: {
   "./assets/images/expo-icon.png": "./assets/images/expo-icon@2x.png",
   "./assets/images/slack-icon.png": "./assets/images/slack-icon@2x.png",
   "@expo/vector-icons": "expo-web",
   expo: "expo-web",
   "react-native$": "react-native-web",
   'react-native-svg$': 'react-native-web-svg',
      "babel-runtime/regenerator": require.resolve("babel-runtime/regenerator"),
  },
 },
};
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: For completely unknown reasons it now seems to works perfectly. I have not restarted my computer or anything. If anyone has a similar error, please share it here. If it was just about restarting the terminal, then try that. In the meantime do not consider the question answered. Best,

Comment: were you able to update your Expo version past 30? I've had issues with RNW and Expo 32

Comment: yes ! But not yet on web yet. will go try it again next week!